# SQL to LINQ - Multiple Group By Statements and a Join

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity

Working to develop a LINQ query to return the same results as this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
  x.departmentid, 
  Count(x.transactionid) 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      t.id AS transactionid, 
      tp.departmentid AS departmentid 
    FROM 
      history.transactions t 
      JOIN history.transactionproducts tp ON t.id = tp.transactionid 
    GROUP BY 
      t.id, 
      tp.departmentid
  ) AS x 
GROUP BY 
  x.departmentid
```

I'm struggling to figure out how I can group by the departmentid multiple times in LINQ.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var deptTransactionsCount = from transaction in transactions
                                        join product in transactionProducts on transaction.Id equals product.TransactionId
                                        group transaction by new { product.TransactionId, product.DepartmentId }
                                        into groupedbyTransAndDept
                                        select new
                                                   {
                                                       DepartmentID = groupedbyTransAndDept.Key.DepartmentId,
                                                       TotalTransactionsCount = groupedbyTransAndDept.Count()
                                                   };
```

Again, I'm not sure how to account for the multiple group by statements.

Here's the results from the SQL query:
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMcBY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special to account for multiple groupings.  You have a derived table, which is one grouping.  That's one query.  From that, you do another grouping.  That's another query.

```
var deptTransactionsCount = (
    from dept in (
        from t in transactions
        join tp in transactionProducts on t.Id equals tp.TransactionId
        group tp by new { tp.TransactionId, tp.DepartmentId } into groupedbyTransAndDept
        from transAndDept in groupedbyTransAndDept
        select new
        {
            transAndDept.TransactionId,
            transAndDept.DepartmentId
        })
    group dept by dept.DepartmentId into groupedByDept
    select new
    {
        DepartmentId = groupedByDept.Key,
        Count = groupedByDept.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

And because it's LINQ, you can factor out the inner query if that makes it easier to understand what it's doing.

```
var innerQuery =
    from t in transactions
    join tp in transactionProducts on t.Id equals tp.TransactionId
    group tp by new { tp.TransactionId, tp.DepartmentId } into groupedbyTransAndDept
    from transAndDept in groupedbyTransAndDept
    select new
    {
        transAndDept.TransactionId,
        transAndDept.DepartmentId
    };

var deptTransactionsCount = (
    from dept in innerQuery
    group dept by dept.DepartmentId into groupedByDept
    select new
    {
        DepartmentId = groupedByDept.Key,
        Count = groupedByDept.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can simplify it.

```
var result = transactions.Select(transaction => new
        {
            DepartmentId = transactionProducts.FirstOrDefault(product =>
                product.TransactionId == transaction.Id)?.DepartmentId,
            TransactionIdCount = transactionProducts.Where(product =>
                product.TransactionId == transaction.Id)
                .Select(product => product.TransactionId).Count()
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

From my experience, it is difficult to do groups and joins with Linq, you could create a view in the database and use that instead.